# update datetime to null using C# ForceClient in the "Salesforce.Force" namespace

Tags: c#

Here is the c# code I am using to update salesforce object.

```
public async Task<SalesForceResponse> Update(string recordId, BaseEntity record, string SObjectTypeName)
    {
        WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(ConfigSettings.Instance.Proxy, false, new string[] { });
        var auth = await GetAuthorizationInfo();

        using (var messageHandler = new HttpClientHandler())
        {
            messageHandler.Proxy = proxy;
            messageHandler.UseProxy = true;
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(messageHandler))
            using (var client = new ForceClient(auth.InstanceUrl, auth.AccessToken, auth.ApiVersion, httpClient))
            {
                var retVal = await client.UpdateAsync(SObjectTypeName, recordId, record);
                return new SalesForceResponse() { Success = retVal.Success, Id = retVal.Id, Errors = new List<string>() { retVal.Errors.ToString() } };

            }
        }

    }
```

I want to update one DateTime field inside "record" object to null, I know forceclinet will skip null values so I need an alternate method to updte null value in salesforce.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to specify JsonProperty for your datetime field

```
[JsonProperty("**datetimefieldName**", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include)]
```

or you can create the serializer yourself.

```
JsonSerializer _jsonWriter = new JsonSerializer {
                             NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
                         };
```